# Git automatically declaring subprojects as submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

I had my project in a 'www' folder.

In 'www/vendor', I cloned other projects from GitHub. I just cloned them, never did anything to make them submodules or subtrees.

Quite often, I worked on these subprojects, contributed upstream, etc. I just had to `cd` to a directory like 'www/vendor/projectX' and use Git commit there, and it was as if they were independent projects. Then I could go back up to 'www' and make a commit there that would acknowledge the changes in the subprojects into my main project. All great and simple.

Then I moved 'www/vendor' into 'www/php/vendor'. I did `git add php` and committed the change, and now all my 'www/php/vendor/*' folders are completely empty on the remote server. On my machine, the files are still here but `git status` says there is nothing to commit.

I don't know but it looks as if all the subprojects had automatically been declared as submodules when I moved them. However I see no trace of it: no .gitmodule, nothing in the modules folder. And this is what I get when I `git rm`:

```
$ git rm php/vendor/projectX
error: the following submodule (or one of its nested submodules) uses a .git directory:
php/vendor/projectX
```

Am I missing something or is this a Git bug? I'd like to go back to the way I worked before, without deleting the .git folders of subprojects or using submodules.

I've been using Git 1.8.4 and 1.8.5.2 in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior of Git. It doesn't know what to do with these repos other than declare them submodules.

You could ignore the paths where you keep other Git repos. Especially if you update them with a package/dependency manager and keep the lock file in the root repo.

Comment: Thanks but I am confused why it changed all of a sudden when I just moved a folder, that's weird. I guess Git was modified at some point to force using submodules or subtrees.

I like to keeps subprojects files self-contained in my parent project, so I guess I'll just have to use submodules now. I didn't need to learn new commands, but if I have to...

Comment: This is because you didn't ignore these paths in your root `.gitignore`. So when they are not ignored, Git should track these paths somehow. Since it see the `.git` folder it keeps their history separate. Which is the definition of Git submodules.

Comment: Aaah, you nailed it ! The subproject folders must have been tracked in the super-project at a time when the .git subfolder was not there, and then they continued to be tracked even after the .git folder appeared after cloning. It resulted in a behavior which was similar to subtrees, whithout the hassle of having to call something like `$ git merge --squash -s subtree projectX`. Thank you, it's all clear now.